# mysql - get all post with comment count and user from users, posts and comments table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables of users, posts and comments. Users table fields are

Id, name,   gender, phone

posts table fields are

post_id, user_id, posts, time

comments table fields are

id, user_id, comment, post_id, time

i wants to get value of these fields

name, gender, posts, time, count(comments)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: you need to `JOIN` among the table. that's it...

Comment: I did join but where no comments against post it shows null. I need the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    x.*, CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) AS name, u.Gender AS gender 
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.id , p.post, p.date_time, p.user_id AS uid, COUNT(c.post_id) AS 'count'
    FROM
        posts p
    LEFT JOIN
        comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
    GROUP BY
        p.id
) x 
LEFT JOIN
    users u ON u.id = uid
```

Comment: Welcome @IliasAhmed

Answer (score 1):

Try as this:

Here 0 will replace if comments.id is null

```
SELECT User.name, User.gender, posts.posts, count(distinct ifnull(comments.id, 0)) as commentcount
FROM User
JOIN posts on user.id = posts.user_id
JOIN comments on user.id =comments.user_id
GROUP User.name, posts.posts
```

If you want to group with gender  add User.gender to group by.

Comment: Always add all the non aggregate in the group by.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.